# Include third party libraries by git cloning them into my own code

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am new to C++ build systems. I am using CLION on MACOS with CMAKE.

I am aware of the practice of installing a third-party library using my OS package manager, then referencing the header of that library in my make file.

However, I would rather ship out a fully functional executable that includes the library it is dependant upon into its own executable  - since I am only using basic helper stuff and I believe it will lead to a smoother experience for a customer.

I am thinking of setting up a project directory structure as follows :

```
project
  /library
    /libressl-v3.3.0
```

Then, issuing a git clone commit command such as:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v3.3.0 https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable.git
```

into the libressl-v3.3.0 directory.

My question; are there any redflags to doing a procedure like this?

My second question is able to the technical side. What is the mininum configuration change to CMakeLists.txt that I need to make for the compiler to pick up the librassl checkout? My current file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(myapp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(myapp main.cpp src/txn.h)
```

Comment: You could use this to download and build the dependency as part of your project build: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: "are there any redflags to doing a procedure like this?" - After including 3d-party project into your own one, you become **responsible** for all problems in building this project. Otherwise, I see no problems in this approach. For "pick up" an including 3d-party project in CMake, use `add_subdirectory`, `ExternalProject_Add` or any other way.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "After including a third-party project into your own one, you become responsible for all problems in building this project". True, but I am targetting a non-technical consumer-level app, and I think the extra load on the customer to update each dependancy independently is too cumbersome. Think of what chrome did when they packaged flash updates into the browser.

Comment: `I am targetting a non-technical consumer-level app`, `I would rather ship out a fully functional executable that includes the library it is dependant upon into its own executable` the normal process would be to either statically or dynamically link against the those libraries and if you link dynamically you can ship those libs with your application. Depending on the license of the library you are even required to link dynamically.

Comment: `and I think the extra load on the customer to update each dependancy independently is too cumbersome.` if you deploy to a system without package manger you would like statically or dynamically and ship the libraries with the application (bundling). If you target a system with a package manager you would write a “recipe” for that package manager that lists the dependencies so that the customer does not need to take care about those. Especially for libs like ssl libs it is desired that they are uptodate.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay: You have asked **two questions** in one question post. By itself this doesn't fit good for Stack Overflow: here we prefers single problem per question post. But even separated,  your questions are not good: The first question ( "are there any redflags to doing a procedure like this?") is mostly **opinion-based**. The second question (how to include 3d party project) is asked many times, and you don't provide any specifics for your case.